# Getting "prompt aborted by user" javascript exception

Tags: javascript

I am getting **"Components.Exception("prompt aborted by user", Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"**  exception when I am using "windows.location.href" in javasacript. My Code is:

```
function checkCookie(){
var value = null;   
var cookieName='UserDetailsCookie'; 
value=ReadCookie(cookieName);   
if(value != null){          
    var url='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/admin.jsp';
    window.location.href = url;     
}
document.loginForm.userName.focus();
```

}

```
function ReadCookie(name)
{
  name += '=';
  var parts = document.cookie.split(/;\s*/);
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
  {
    var part = parts[i];
    if (part.indexOf(name) == 0)
          return part.substring(name.length);
      }
  return null;
```

}

and I am calling this method on onLoad event of body

```
<body onLoad="javascript:checkCookie();">
```

In anyone knows why this exception throws please?

Comment: I get the same error when doing a jQuery.ajax call.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703317/troubleshooting-jquery-ajax-call-using-generic-handler-in-asp-net

Comment: @MacGyver: Thanks for reply, it's already resolve for me.

Comment: If you solved it, can you write your solution as an answer please.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is due to the line

```
document.loginForm.userName.focus();
```

because this will cancel the loading of your URL done with the window.location.href = 'xxx'.

Anyway, in general there should NOT be any line of code after setting the location.href property.

Hope that helps, I know it's old but I answered for moomoochoo since his comment isn't "that" old.